# Prove that that the set $P = \{p\mid \text{Prime}(p) \land p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}\}$ is infinite

Tags: prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I was able to prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers
but I'm not able prove that there are infinitely many primes that are equivalent to $3 \pmod{4}$. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If there are finitely many primes $q_i \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ look at $4 \prod_{i=1}^4 q_i-1$. It works because $\varphi(\varphi(n)) = 1$.